# TypeError: Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable. Why is this happening?

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a new user using DRF. The code actually creates the user but I get a 500 error saying that user is not JSON serializable. I would like to get rid of this error. Here are how my files look

views.py

```
class UserCreateAPIView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EndUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NewUserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

serializers.py

```
class NewUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.EndUser
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'title', 'user_type', 'packages', 'practice_area',
                  'office_phone', 'level', 'companies', 'country', 'password', 'firm', 'sectors', 'verticals', 'user_ptr')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
```

urls.py

```
router.register('new-user', views.UserCreateAPIView)
```

Enduser inherits User. Would anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `user_ptr` is, as far as I undrestand it a `OneToOneField` to `User`, so you will need to use an extra serializer to serialize the `User` specific elements, or leave the `user_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `user_ptr` field which is, If I understood it correctly the `OneToOneField` Django constructed for its model inheritance:

```
class NewUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.EndUser
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'title'
          , 'user_type', 'packages', 'practice_area'
          , 'office_phone', 'level', 'companies', 'country'
          , 'firm', 'sectors', 'verticals', 'password'
        )  # no  user_ptr
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
```

While Django will hash passwords, it is not a good idea to mark the `password` as a field that can be read. It means that you will retrieve the password hash, and although that might still require a lot of computational effort to obtain the real password, it is still not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Could you elaborate a bit more on the password thing? I entered the code you added and I don't see that it made a change.

Comment: @bballboy8: did you set it to `write_only_fields`? The idea is that you normally do not want to *retrieve* the password when you thus make a GET request.

Comment: Yes. Do I also need to remove it from fields?

Comment: @bballboy8: Did some research, apparently you specify `write_only` as parameter of the `password` field.

Comment: I just made the change you said. I still don't see a difference in the admin page.

Comment: @bballboy8: ah, but you only use it as `CreateAPIView`, not as `ListAPIView`, etc. Then it does not make any difference, since then you do not *retrieve* any value, you only *create* new data.

Comment: The code posted names it CreateApiView, but inherits ModelViewSet, so it is a problem, but if you don't call the route you won't see the payload.

Comment: @Melvyn: well, either it should be renamed to `UserCreateModelViewSet`, or inherit from `CreateAPIView`, but now it gives the "impression" (through naming) that it only creates* records :s.